# Using AVPlayer for playing video - video stops at some point

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avplayer

I am using few `UIViewController`s in the row for presentation. On every of those screens I need to play video.
This is the code that I am using on every of those screens for playing a video:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"video" withExtension:@"mp4"];

AVPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:videoURL];
AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];

[avPlayerLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, videoWidth, videoHeight)];

_videoView.layer.sublayers = nil;
[_videoView.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];

[avPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
[avPlayer play];
```

First screen is UIViewController where user can select one of the scenarios. On the home screen I am also showing the video using code that I wrote above. User can click on the next button and then I am showing the next screen.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

HomeViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home_vc"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

When scenario is completed I am showing home screen again and user can select next scenario.

After a few screens I have problem with video.
On the place where I should see video I can see just a black screen. I am guessing that this problem is related to memory but I couldn't find solution.

Comment: You're probably retain your controller somehow. Please add code you use in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidDisappear` call `[avPlayer pause]` method, remove any observers and set your `avPlayer` and `avPlayerLayer` refrence to nil

Comment: Also when I add this still have the same problem.